# NFC foreground dispatch not working

Tags: android, android-intent, tags, nfc, intentfilter

I'm trying to make it so that when I open my app and scan a tag, it will display a toast with the ID of the tag. The problem is, every time I scan a tag it brings up a list of applications and I can choose mine among them.

I tried to implement the foreground dispatch mechanism, but then it does not show anything at all (it neither crashes, nor does it display the toast).

This is the main code:

```
public class loginPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private String serialId = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "NFC NOT supported on this devices!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } else if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "NFC NOT Enabled!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)) {
            try {
                byte[] tagId = tag.getId();
                serialId = toHexString(tagId);
                Log.d("[ReadCardTools]", "Serial Number: " + serialId);
                Toast.makeText(this, serialId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                serialId = "ERROR";
            }
        }
    }

    public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexArray = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        int v;
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v / 16];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v % 16];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
}
```

The manifest contains the following additions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true"/>
```

and

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
           android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

The filter is:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
</tech-list>
</resources>
```

logcat only says "D/PersonaManager: isNFCAllowed" every time I scan a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreground dispatch system, when enabled as a catch-all (i.e. with the last two arguments of the method `enableForegroundDispatch()` set to `null`), will send TAG_DISCOVERED intents to your activity. Since you only listen for TECH_DISCOVERED intents (and ignore all others) you won't display the toast upon tag discovery.

You will therefore need to also act upon receiving a TAG_DISCOVERED intent in `onNewIntent`:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) ||
        NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        if (tag != null) {
            serialId = toHexString(tag.getId());
            Log.d("[ReadCardTools]", "Serial Number: " + serialId);
            Toast.makeText(this, serialId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between **ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED** and **ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED**?